# counting only executable file in linux not all the file which have executable permission

Tags: linux, shell

I want to count only files which are executable ,

I tried

```
grep -lR '^--x' * | wc -l
```

but this also count the files which have executable permission but not really executable.

what is the correct way ?

Comment: What does it mean to have executable permission but not really executable?

Comment: @FatalError I read that line 3 times... didn't get what does it mean....

Comment: also your regex (apart from `-` should be `.`) is just for owner executable....do you really mean that? no matter if there is a `x` for group and everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use some find command with options

This would print only executables files in the /tmp location

```
find /tmp -perm +111 -type f | wc -l</ br>
```

For Directories

```
find /tmp -perm +111 -type d | wc -l</ br>
```

Comment: A note that `-perm +xxx` has been deprecated since 2005 and is in recent versions no longer supported. You should now use `-perm /111` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between an executable file and a not-executable file on unix is the "executable" flag.
A file with that flag is always executable. However, it can be that there is nothing to interpret that type of file, but that is not Unix's problem :-)

Comment: directory is executable ??

Comment: Yes it is, you execute it by going into it. In Unix, everything is a file. A directory is a file that can contain other files. Executing this file/directory, opens it up to show the other files inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to ignore the file type ([`bcd-`]) and rw flags. (Also use `ls` to generate the data, and `grep` to filter it.):

```
ls -lR | grep '^...x' | wc -l
```